# Setting up postgresql with Ruby on Rails (MacOS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Hello I am a new learner. I am using a Mac and I am trying to setup to work with Ruby on Rails and postgresql. I have installed postgresql and followed the following guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-macos?fbclid=IwAR178wfP7LSEi1-kGsfYhUVS0VPXSCdvJv4r8vqhi7Bxnh9qIlVyIjv6c_M

However, ended up messing my /.bash_profile file and I am really confused where is the problem.
I don't really understand how the things work but I guess it's a good time to learn.
I tried to run the following command:  `source ~/.bash_profile` and I get the following output in my terminal:
`-bash: /Users/filipkucherenkov/.bash_profile: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

My my .bash_profile looks like this.

```
    [[ -s "/Users/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/USERNAME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
    PS1="\$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt) $PS1
    eval "$(rbenv init -)"
    PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
    export PATH
    export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
    export PGDATA=/usr/local/var/postgres
    export PGHOST=/tmp
    export Path="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12.4/bin:$PATH"
```

I will be really happy if someone helps me to resolve this problem ...

Comment: You're missing at `"` at the end of the `PS1="...` line.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that however I still get a weird message `-bash: /Users/username/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt: No such file or directory`

Comment: It actually doesn't sort the problem it messes up somehow with the terminal and disables it.

Comment: You'll also need to replace "username" and "USERNAME" in the line above with your real username or use `~` to refer to your home directory.

Comment: I changed that and it still gives me  `-bash: /Users/filip/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt: No such file or directory` when trying to enter the command `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @Filkata22, are you using rvm and have you installed it?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Yes, I have install it.

Comment: That's strange that you need additional steps for installation of postresql. (without adding additional configuration to profile).

The only thing you need to do it's install brew package and that's all.
I'd recommend to reinstall it (don't forget to clear you config that was added to profile).

Here is official instruction.
https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/
`brew install postgresql`